# scala map sequence of tuples to vector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, collections

I have a spark dataframe like

```
val df = Seq((1, 2), (2, 1), (1,2)).toDF()
```

when collected as `val local = df.collect` the result is `Array([1,2], [2,1], [1,2])`

How can I map this rather to 2 separate vectors like

```
val col1: Seq(1,2,1)
val col2: Seq(2,1,2)
```

Comment: have you tried `unzip`

Comment: that leads to `error: No implicit view available from org.apache.spark.sql.Row => (T1, T2).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To split *before* collecting - you can use two separate `select` operations:

```
val col1: Array[Int] = df.select("_1").as[Int].collect()
val col2: Array[Int] = df.select("_2").as[Int].collect()
```

But - beware that the calculation to create `df` would be executed **twice** unless you persist it (e.g. by calling `df.cache()` beforehand).

To split *after* collecting:

```
val arr = df.as[(Int, Int)].collect()
val (col1, col2) = arr.unzip
```

p.s. all this assumes you're using Spark 1.6 or newer.

Comment: That's what the second option does - collects both as a single array and then splits it. You can inline it into `df.as[(Int, Int)].collect().unzip`